# How Does @ResponseBody annotation binds data on void methods in a controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller

I searched for the use of @ResponseBody annotation and I found that this annotation binds data to the response according to the return type of the method here(https://zetcode.com/springboot/responsebody/),But today I got an old project where I saw a controller method like this:-

```
@Controller
public class MyConroller {
    @Autowired
    JsonMapper mapper;

@RequestMapping(value = "/methodURL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody 
public void controllerMethod(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    
            HttpSession hs = req.getSession(false);
            Map<String, Object> map = service.getList();
            mapper.WritecInJson(res, map);

        
    }

}
```

JASON Mapper-:

```
public class JsonMapper {
        
        public void WritecInJson(HttpServletResponse res,Object object)
        {

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        MediaType jsonMimeType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
        if(jsonConverter.canWrite(object.getClass(), jsonMimeType)){
            
            jsonConverter.write(object , jsonMimeType, new ServletServerHttpResponse(res));

        }
    }
```

As you can see the method in the controller class has void as its return type. So, How @ResponseBody binds data to the response through this void method?

Comment: It just indicates that this method returns a body and not a view. If you would remove it it would fallback to the default request to view handling and try to render a few. So currently it is only preventing that. I would ditch the void and just return the map and thus also remove the `JsonMapper`.

Comment: Yes..that will work ..but in this case how it is identifying the body to return...Beacuse it is void method and it is generating response..

Comment: It doesn't (as I said) it only prevents it from doing the regular view lookup for void methods. As the response is written in the method itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir....After your first comment I did more research on it and now i got it...actually I'm new to spring framework ,that's why i got confused when i saw such type of method in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ResponseBody
```

must defined a return type. If you really don’t need to define a method with return type. You can use `HttpServletResponse`.getOutputStream() to write back the response content.